# What chemicals and what amount is used to start up a 3300 gallon 14'x42" summer wave pool

Tags: pool

Just bought a summer wave pool cz need to know what and how much pool chemicals to add

Comment: Di-hydrogen monoxide... Lots of di-hydrogen monoxide.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general answer for this type of question.  The specifics and quantity of chemicals greatly depend upon:

1. your local water conditions:  water source, minerals, age of pipe
2. pool liner type
3. filter type
4. pump type
5. plumbing type
6. climate:  rainfall, humidity, salty air, etc.
7. usage patterns
8. and other possible variations like overhanging vegetation, runoff,
   local critters, etc., etc.

The best advice is found at your local friendly neighborhood pool chemical supply store.  Take care to select a good one.  Maybe you have coworkers or friends with a pool:  seek out their advice about the best pool shop in town.

Take a sample of your pool water in a clean container; also take your pool's details above.  At least some stores do the analysis for free and provide you with a custom list of chemicals, quantities, and frequency of application for proper treatment.

Of course the business wants to sell you as much product as possible.  If you are not experienced managing a pool's chemical balance, follow their advice closely until you get a feel for how your pool behaves—which could take two or three months of daily sampling and maintenance.